# Difference between apoc.periodic.iterate and apoc.periodic.commit when deleting lots of nodes?

Tags: neo4j

What's the difference between these two lines?

```
call apoc.periodic.iterate("MATCH (n:Nodes) return n", "DETACH DELETE n", {batchSize:10000, iterateList:true})"

call apoc.periodic.commit("match (n:Nodes) limit {limit} detach delete n RETURN count(*)",{limit:10000})
```

What is the best way to delete lots of nodes?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The procedure `apoc.periodic.iterate` takes two queries :

- the first one to create a set of nodes in your example
- the second one will be executed for each result of the first query

So in your example your match all the `Node` of your database, and then you delete them with a batch size of 10000.

The procedure `apoc.periodic.commit` takes only one query, and the procedure will execute the query again, and again and again ... tilt its result is **0**.

So in your example, you take the first 10000 nodes and delete them. You repeat this behaviour till there is no more `Node` in your database.

**To resume**, both queries give the same result, but not in the same way. The `apoc.periodic.iterate` will take a little more RAM than the `apoc.periodic.commit` (the procedure needs to build the set of nodes at first), but one good thing with it is that you can use all yours CPU, via the configuration `parallel:true` (but be carefull to locks).

If you have a really huge number of nodes to delete, I recommand you to use the `apoc.periodic.commit`.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer!

Comment: But I could also change the first one to be like a single query:

`call apoc.periodic.iterate("MATCH (n:Nodes) DETACH DELETE n", {batchSize:10000, iterateList:true})"`

correct?

Comment: The breakdown of `iterate()` into 2 queries is what allows it to be performant. It won't hold the entire result set in memory, just pull as results are found and then execute the inner query on each batch. The single query call above, if it were possible, would behave the same way as the match and delete query without the procedure call, in that it would have to hold references to every single one of those nodes in memory and commit in a single batch, which could be a problem on a large graph. You could blow up your heap.